# Make a countdown without freezing application on Android?

Tags: java, android

How can I make a countdown without to freeze the Application in Android ? For example a countdown which is counts the 10 to a 1 down .

Comment: with java and android is that possible :-)

Comment: have a look at it http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: We need to see your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can get from your question, you are most likely having trouble because you are doing some sort of count-down in the main (UI) Thread. This will definitely cause the app to freeze for the duration of the timer. Simply use a timer, and do something like this:

```
//global variables
private int currTime = 10;
private TextView myTimer;//need to initialize this in your layout using findViewById, or programmatically

final Timer t = new Timer();
currTime = 10;
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {//You need this, or a Handler to ensure the UI is changed on the correct thread.
            currTime--;
            myTimer.setText(currTime);//myTimer is a global reference to your TextView.
            if (currTime == 0)
                t.cancel();
        });
    }
}, 10000);//note that this is the duration in milliseconds (1/1000 of a second) - so 10000 for 10 seconds.
```